# Link class function calls to modules loaded in a process

Tags: c++, winapi

What I am trying to do is inject into a process and then use the modules that are available within that process. That's pretty straight forward by using `GetProcAddress()` and requesting individual functions as needed.

However, I have third party API files that I am trying to utilize as well. These files contain classes that I can use to make various API calls. When importing them into my project and attempting to compile them I get the `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol` error. This error stems from the fact I am not importing the lib files. The problem is I cannot import them because I do not have access to the lib files. I'd like to use the existing loaded modules in the process I am injecting into.

I am struggling with finding a way to put these two pieces together. How can I link the various function calls within the class files to modules already loaded into a process? If this is not possible what approach should be taken?

EDIT: Modified sentence about lib files

Comment: *I cannot import them because..* - really ? *I'd like to use the existing loaded modules in the process* - in this case you must not want inject to process at all, but only use  existing loaded modules in the process

Comment: Ok. So let's say we go your way and open a handle on the process in order to access the loaded modules instead. This problem still exists- how can you link the various function calls within the classes to the remote processes modules?

Comment: how is at all related import libs/linking and some process and it loaded modules ?!

Comment: I appreciate your attempt at answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the LIB. Otherwise the references to the functions can't be resolved by the linker.

You can bypass this by using LoadLibary/GetProcAddress for this functions to. For classes this will be complicated.

But what is your problem including the LIB into your DLL.

When Your module is injected into the other program the required DLLs are loaded into the process too. If they are already loaded the loaded DLLs will be used and the "existing DLLs" (already loaded DLLs) in the process are used.

A problem might only be the DLL search sequence... Remember: If you use USER32.DLL functions you get the already loaded copy and use it too. No second User32.dll is loaded when you use the import library.

If the DLLs are not loaded they are implicitly loaded, when you module is injected into the process.

Comment: I had not considered the DLL search sequence bit. That's a fair point. However, it was poorly worded in the original post. I do not have access to the lib files. I need to do what you mentioned with the loablibrary/getprocaddress but I am not certain how to do that with classes. That's why the question was how to actually link various function calls in a remote process to a class. Thank you for taking the time!